# Audit Trailing System in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, audit-trail

I am trying to build an audit trailing system for my Oracle-Java application. I have done lots of search in Google. Found some solutions, mostly suggested to use trigger. But problem using this approach is I won't be able to track which application user is making changes. I want to track user ids also along with the changes. Can you guys suggest me what would be best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the database to audit the information, you'll need to do something to let the database know what application user is logged in to a particular session.  There are a variety of ways to do this, many of which depend on the application architecture.  Assuming that this is a standard 3-tier application, one approach is to create a context

```
SQL> create context login_ctx using login_pkg;

Context created.

SQL> create or replace package login_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure set_user( p_username in varchar2 );
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package body login_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure set_user( p_username in varchar2 )
  4    as
  5    begin
  6      dbms_session.set_context( 'LOGIN_CTX', 'USER_NAME', p_username );
  7    end;
  8* end;
SQL> /

Package body created.
```

Your application would then need to call the `login_pkg.set_user` procedure whenever a new application user is going to be using a particular session.  If this is a three-tier application with a connection pool, this would need to happen every time a user requested a connection from the pool.

```
SQL> exec login_pkg.set_user( 'Justin' );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In your trigger code (or elsewhere in PL/SQL), you can then query the context to determine the identity of the current application user.

```
SQL> select sys_context( 'LOGIN_CTX', 'USER_NAME' )
  2    from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('LOGIN_CTX','USER_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Justin
```

If there are other elements that you want to audit, you can set whatever arbitrary attributes you want in your context (i.e. you can pass in the client IP address or a session ID or anything else the middle tier has access to).

Other options include using proxy users in the database for your application users, setting a package variable rather than using a context, or having the application do the auditing.